# onTouchEvent for whole app, without an activity

Tags: android, touch

I am developing an android app which tracks touch events for the whole application. For that purpose, I want to override `onTouchEvent()` without an activity; i.e., inside a simple Java class, I don't whether it's possible. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot arbitrarily override `onTouchEvent`, particularly in a "simple Java class", i.e. one that does not extend a `View`.

### Solution 1

If you want to capture all touches to your app, override [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) in your main layout. So, if your main layout is a `LinearLayout`, do something like:

```
public class MyTouchLayout extends LinearLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Do whatever with your touch event
        return false; // Do not prevent the rest of the layout from being touched
    }
}
```

Then, in your XML, you'd use:

```
<com.example.MyTouchLayout
    ...
    >

    <!-- The rest of your layout -->

</com.example.MyTouchLayout>
```

### Solution 2

This is by far the simpler solution, though I've had varying luck with it in the past and would *never* suggest that you reply upon it.

You can simply get the `View` that contains all your content (the root `View`, a `LinearLayout` above), then give it a listener.

```
View v = findViewById(android.R.id.content); // Find the root View; you may have to give it your own ID in the XML, and use that
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i followed your solution 2, but the Log inside the OnTouchListener will prints on only when we touches a empty screen in activity, it does not prints the Log when we clicks the button on the same activity, is there any solution for this

Comment: Maybe try Solution 1? As I said, Solution 2 is unreliable.

Comment: actually i am creating a library which tracks all touches, i dont want the user who is using the library to extends my class, just they need to call a single method to track the touches, is there any way to do it